# Clustering unrelated (with no correlation) data

Tags: model-based-clustering

The objective of clustering analysis is to group data with similar characteristics in clusters, but in this case, I want to find the most unrelated data to group into clusters. In my particular case, I have 100 weather stations during one year with a 1hr interval, and I want to group the most similar weather stations(I performed this step with K-means using the correlation distance via MATLAB, but I can use R or Python). But now, I want to perform the inverse, i.e., group in the same cluster unrelated (with no correlation) weather stations .

Is this possible? If yes, how? Or, should I use others techniques to execute my idea?

The main idea is to use the groups to prove a concept often used in wind power designated as statistical power smoothing effect ([pdf](https://www.uni-oldenburg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/physik/ag/ehf/enmet/publications/wind/conference/2000/ewea_kassel/reduction_of_windpower_prediction_error_by_spatial_smoothing_effects.pdf)). Basically, there is a statistical power smoothing effect in the wind power data, if you considered data with different features (e.g., different weather conditions). I want to use this grouping to show if I carefully grouping my weather stations (that will be transformed in wind power), then I can minimize the fluctuations. So far I applied k-means algorithm to select the weather stations with the same behavior, and now I want to explore the opposite. Probably, the technique that I need is not clustering, but so far I search and nothing came up.

@Pere: Yes, I also expected what you mentioned. Can you provide some reference to understand how I can compute the correlation inverse distance?

@Dougal: I want diverse groups, as in the normal cluster.  To be honest the goal was to split the data in the same number of the "normal" clustering, in my case 9.

@ Pere: Thank you for the example. But I didn't achieve the expected results since, in my case, some clusters are very close to the ones obtained with the "normal" cluster. Probably it is better to try a trial and error test (adding/removing weather stations) to understand the weather stations that I should combine to smooth my signal.

Comment: well, you said it yourself, you want to perform the "inverse", so you can try to take the inverse (algebric) of your correlation matrix

Comment: Because this is such an unusual request, could you please provide more specifics about what this grouping is intended to achieve?  It will come down to this question (abstractly): given two candidate groupings, exactly how would you decide which one is a better solution than the other?

Comment: You just need to define a "distance" that is inverse of usual distance. It won't fit the definition of distance in algebra or topology but for most clustering methods that shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, I would expect rather strange groups and some instability among groups.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. To be honest I only know how to perform the inverse of functions! Can you please provide how I can perform in my correlation matrix? or indicate a reference/toolbox?

Comment: Are you really trying to find a single, diverse group? Do you want as many diverse groups as possible?

Comment: The description is reminiscent of [graph cliques vs. independent sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Maximum_independent_sets_and_maximum_cliques). So the suggestion of @Pere is similar to "inverting the weights" to form a [complement graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph). Perhaps a similarity based approach would be better than a distance based approach? (e.g. something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering_of_networks)?)

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @Manuel: I don't have references, but I made an example.

Comment: @Manuel - the k-means is a blunt instrument.  It assumes the variance of the various clusters are uniform - the real world doesn't actually do that.  "All models are wrong ..." but some are more wrong than others and they have to be evaluated before they inform next steps.  A gaussian mixture model (GMM) is a decent higher-tech check for your k-means.  If the minimum AICc happens at the same cluster count AND if the variances of the GMM components are all very close to each other, then you might go forward with k-means.  Otherwise, don't be married to 9 clusters.

Comment: The inverse of clustering is identifying outliers.  You collect the samples which do not fall into a cluster by any criteria into a separate group.  Calling this group a "cluster" is misleading but this seems to be what you are asking.

Comment: For a somewhat more intelligent approach, maybe use several clustering methods and collect the outliers which are not accepted into a cluster by any of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

To cluster the less similar points instead of the more similar, you just need to change the distance matrix in a way that the more different the points are, the lesser distance are given. A simple way to do this is just to use any decreasing function of the usual distance.

In your case your usual distance is probably 1-correlation (distance 0 for very correlated points and 1 for uncorrelated), so you can use as distance the inverse of 1-correlation or even 1+correlation.

I'll put an example of clustering the most different point using geographical distances - that is, clusters will have the most distant points instead of the closest neighbours.

I'll start with the distances between European cities found in http://www.mapcrow.info/european_travel_distance.html (in my code this matrix is the dataset "distsciutats").

```
distinv<-(1/distsciutats)
di<-as.dist(distinv)
fiti<-hclust(di,method="complete")
plot(fiti,main="clustering by inverse geographical distance")
```

[image: clustering by inverse geographical distance]

You can see how the most distant cities are clustered together.

Just for comparison, I clustered the same cities using geographical distance, as usual.

```
 dc<-as.dist(distsciutats)
 fit<-hclust(dc,method="complete")
 plot(fit,main="clustering by geographical distance")
```

[image: clustering by actual distance]

Comment: Little update: since the triangular inequality isn't likely to hold for the inverse of distance, that inverse isn't a distance but just a dissimilarity, which may ruin some desirable properties of clusters.